# Skrollr: Create instant move?

Tags: javascript, html, skrollr

I'm using **Skrollr** to animate `div class="box"` using its `margin-top`, but my issue is that I need an **instant change**, not  **animation** ..

This [**JSbin**](http://jsbin.com/degobovi/3/) Shows what I'm working on, I need the `margin-top` of the red div be `0px` when `data-top-bottom` for `data-anchor-target=".space"` but instantly without animation ...

I'v tried all these properties

```
skrollr.init({
    forceHeight: true,
    smoothScrollingEnabled: false,
    smoothScrollingDuration: 1,
    smoothScrolling: false,
    forceRender: true
});
```

but nothing helped me...

So in another way : Is there any way, to go from `skrollable-before` to `skrollable-after` without passing through `skrollable-between`

Hope there is a way to do that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put an exclamation mark before the values, as documented here https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#preventing-interpolation

```
margin-top: !300px;
margin-top: !0px;
```

http://jsbin.com/degobovi/5/edit