# Skrollr instant popup text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make skrollr (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) show text right away. Right now I can only get text to fade in and out. How can I make it just appear suddenly then disappear?

```
<div id="style" data-100="opacity:0; left:25%;"  data-600="opacity:1;left:25%;" data-    700="opacity:0;left:25%;" >
 Howdy World < /div
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589010/skrollr-create-instant-move/24594446#24594446

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine you could try just using display:none and display:block instead of opacity.

I've found that Skrollr is fantastic for easing and transition stuff. However, if you  just need scroll/viewport based actions and want a little more control you might want to check out http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/.

Comment: Using `visibility:hidden` and `visiblity:visible` gets closer to what she wants, but anyway both make more sense then using `opacity`